# Define PK on multi tenant environment on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I see different opinions about choosing the PK in a multi-tenancy environment. Let's say a have a table Employees. I created my Employee table like this:

```
EmployeeId INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
TenantId INT,
FirstName NVARCHAR(100),
LastName NVARCHAR(100)
```

I know I need to use the TenantId in all my queries, so I created besides a non cluster index on TenantId so I can write some queries like this:

In case I need all Employees for one specific Tenant:

```
Select EmployeeId, FirstName, LastName
where TenantId = 1
```

In case I need one Employees for one specific Tenant:

```
Select EmployeeId, FirstName, LastName
where EmployeeId = 1 and TenantId = 1
```

Testing with about 100000 records and one single Tenant for now on the Employee table I get full scan on the first query (I guess it's normal even if I have a non cluster index defined on TenantId because I have one Tenant in my table so it needs to scan the all table) and index seek on the second one.

Is this a good approach, do I need to add the TenantId in the cluster index too?

Comment: You shouldn't have a scan if there is a non clustered index on TenantId

Comment: @stevenackley . . . Not true.  SQL Server is smart enough not to use such a simple rule under all circumstances.  (I believe what you say is true in some databases such as MySQL and Postgres.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no simple answer to your question.  You seem to have a low-cardinality column and a desire to query on that column.  As a consequence, you will be returning many rows.  You have observed this in the case of one value --> gets all the rows.

If you had 5 tenants randomly distributed in the 100,000 rows, then SQL Server would probably still do a full table scan, because it expects that all pages would have at least one of the records you are looking for.  This is why non-clustered indexes work best on columns with high cardinality (which implies that few rows have any given value).

With a clustered index on `tenant`, then you will find all the rows in 1/5 of the pages.  The query should be faster.  However, the query is still returning a lot of data, so it is an open question whether the faster table scan is much of an overall benefit.

And, this comes at a cost.  `INSERT`s no longer occur at the end of the table, so page splits become much more common.  `UPDATE`s to tenant require deleting and re-inserting data, rather than modifying the record in place (and that additional work can have locking implications).  These can be important considerations.

A common case where clustered indexes are useful on a low-cardinality column is the "most-recent data" problem.  If you have a table and only 1% is the most recent data (or valid or whatever), then a clustered index on that column can be a big win.

Finally, if `tenantid` really is low cardinality, you might consider partitioning the table by this column.  This might give you the best of both worlds, at least for the two queries that you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

PRIMARY KEY is simply a tag to indicate that is the main lookup on the table! The real question is which key do you make the CLUSTERED index? Personally from what you've posted, what I've seen in the past and knowing the engine - I'd cluster on TentantId, EmployeeId but also add a nonclustered unique key on EmployeeId which is your surrogate key. Because you cluster on TentantId and the nature of B+ Trees then your tenant's will be together (in order). Also, lends itself to partitioning later on....

Comment: It's really kind of confuse :( because I read that in case we use both columns as PK, EmployeeId should be first and then TenantId after because Employee is the most selective column

Comment: That's fine for pulling back single rows, but, do you have any queries that pull back a few hundred/thousand rows - if you cluster on the surrogate key EmployeeId and you are specifying TenantId = 4 then that data isn't grouped together - it's scattered across all the extents in the table so performance won't be as good - basically that's why you'd index both. The clustered key has a copy of the non-clustered keys so bear that in mind. Depends what you are doing though.